# Sealed keyword in leaf node classes

Tags: c#, optimization

While I understand that sealed can be used for security reasons, a few people use the sealed keyword on leaf nodes as an optimization technique.

How does this help optimization? Why isn't the compiler smart enough to figure this out itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does compiler optimize virtual methods implemented by a sealed class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770547/how-does-compiler-optimize-virtual-methods-implemented-by-a-sealed-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sealed class, calls to virtual methods can bypass the usual virtual method lookup and go directly to the most-derived virtual method implementation instead. In principle, the compiler/JIT could also inline these calls.

The compiler can't figure it out for non-sealed classes, because any code could come along after compilation and inherit from your class: the compiler must assume the worst case.

Comment: Sort of. The compiler can call the method directly without a virtual lookup if you call the method on the object after construction without assigning it to a variable. Like so `new NonSealedClass().Method();`

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a virtual method which is overridden in a leaf class. This certainly *won't* be overridden any further, so the JIT compiler could potentially inline calls to that method for targets which are known to be of that leaf class. I don't know whether the JIT *actually* performs this optimization, mind you.

Note that in Java, the HotSpot JVM can perform this optimization even for non-final classes, as it's a multi-pass JIT: it can optimistically assume that nothing's going to override a virtual method, and then undo its optimisations if a class is ever loaded that *does* override it. Of course, with methods being virtual by default in Java, this is a bigger deal than it would be in C#. (Even if defaults *shouldn't* matter, they clearly do.)

Personally I don't use `sealed` particularly for optimization or security reasons: I use it because designing for inheritance (properly) is *hard*. I agree with the concept of "design for inheritance or prohibit it" and have generally found that the occasional pain of not being able to derive from a class is more than compensated for by the freedom from worrying about inheritance. YMMV.

Comment: I favour the idea of sealing everything unless supporting inheritance is intended, but the Framework Design Guidelines seems to disagree, which made me a little surprised since there is a lot of sealed classes in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not really help in terms of optimization.  Not what I can see from profiling anyways.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit of a false optimisation; I'd rather use it to make sure that if I'm not *expecting* inheritance I don't *get* inheritance. The compiler still emits all instance calls (to classes) as virtual calls, but *potentially* the JIT could optimize it differently, and just do a null check and static call, if not overridden. Possibly.

There are some more esoteric cases, for example when the presence of a particular interface would cause it to be treated differently at runtime - but to exploit *those* scenarios (depending on `sealed`) requires runtime code generation via `ILGenerator` etc.